# How to change simple int variable values without making them series int variables?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I would like to make a `ta.ema()` function adaptive so I need to change its `length` value based on some math.

But it expects `simple int` variable for its `length` variable, while a changing `length` value is a `series int` so the function returns with an error.

How to make it work? How to make a `simple int` variable change but with keeping it a Simple (not Series) Int variable. (I don't need its past values so it's not needed to be a `series int`, just be changed sometimes).

Disfunctional example code:

```
AdaptiveFactor = ta.highest(high, 100) / ta.lowest(low, 100)
length = int(20 * AdaptiveFactor / AdaptiveFactor[100])
EMA = ta.ema(close, length)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do that with the built-in function. However, you can achieve that behavior if you simple write the `ema()` function yourself. Its implementation is actually open-source so you can use it.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

pine_ema(src, length) =>
    alpha = 2 / (length + 1)
    sum = 0.0
    sum := na(sum[1]) ? src : alpha * src + (1 - alpha) * nz(sum[1])

AdaptiveFactor = ta.highest(high, 100) / ta.lowest(low, 100)
length = int(20 * AdaptiveFactor / AdaptiveFactor[100])
EMA = pine_ema(close, length)

plot(EMA)
```

Comment: Wow. Never thought the solution is practically to recreate the EMA function.  Prayer Mat purchased from AliExpress.